# Resizing UIImage with CGContext is making my images soft with wrong pixel density

Tags: ios, uiimage, cgcontext, cgimage

I'm building an image manager class to deal with resizing, cropping, etc with  UIImages. I'm using CGContext because of it's speed comparable to UIGraphicsContext with JPEG's from the benchmarks seen here http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/ .

This is my manager class:

```
func resizeImage(exportedWidth width: Int, exportedHeight height: Int, originalImage image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    let cgImage = image.CGImage

    let width = width
    let height = height
    let bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(cgImage)
    let bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(cgImage)
    let colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(cgImage)
    let bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(cgImage)

    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo.rawValue)

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, .High)

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height))), cgImage)

    let scaledImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context).flatMap { UIImage(CGImage: $0) }

    return scaledImage
}
```

Nothing really too crazy, but I'm having trouble when I add it to a subclassed UITextView. I have tried making the image size doubled then compressing it down with an UIImageView to no avail. This code has it properly showing up with the correct size but it looks as if the image pixel to screen pixel ratio is 1:1 instead of the ideal 2:1 for the retina screen on my iPhone SE.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        let textViewWidth: CGFloat = self.view.frame.size.width - 130
        let percentResize = textViewWidth / pickedImage.size.width
        let toBeExportedHeight = pickedImage.size.height * percentResize
        let resizedImage = ImageManipulationManager.sharedInstance.resizeImage(exportedWidth: Int(textViewWidth),exportedHeight: Int(toBeExportedHeight), originalImage: pickedImage)

        let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
        attachment.image = resizedImage
        let attString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
        textView.textStorage.insertAttributedString(attString, atIndex: textView.selectedRange.location)
        textInputbar.layoutIfNeeded()
        textView.becomeFirstResponder()
        print(textView.text.characters.count)
    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An image for a double-resolution screen needs to be double-resolution. That means it should be twice as wide and twice as high as the actual size you want, with a `scale` of 2 attached to the UIImage when you derive it from the CGImage.

Comment: Where exactly would I set the scale to be twice the size. I tried making the size of the bitmapcontext twice the size with the actual image bounds being half of that. However all that ended up happening was the render being the same size and the extra space being black.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you do it when you derive the UIImage from the CGImage.

Comment: So how about the code? I have no idea what attribute I need to be changing. I realize it's scale but I wish that helped me.

Comment: Look at how to make a UIImage from a CGImage: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation: You are saying `UIImage(CGImage: $0)`. So you are missing your chance to set the scale.